# Disabled button at React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer

I have a very confusing task for me and I need your help.
I need to create todos with timers to every task. So user can create his own task -> start timer -> stop timer -> close task. Every task has buttons start and stop.

Problem is that ONLY ONE timer can work at the same time. So another buttons "Start" should be disabled, when even one timer works. 
I suppose that decision near of handleStartClick (to change value button?).

It is the main part of code:

```
    export default class TodoItem extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { secondsStart: this.props.minSeconds }
    this.handleStartClick = this.handleStartClick.bind(this)
  }

    static propTypes = {
    todo: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    deleteTodo: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    completeTodo: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }

  static defaultProps = {
      minSeconds: 0
  }

  getSeconds = () => {
    return ('0' + this.state.secondsStart % 60).slice(-2)
  }

   getMinutes = () => {
    return Math.floor('0' + this.state.secondsStart / 60)
  }
    getHoures = () => {
    return Math.floor(this.state.secondsStart / 60)
  }

  handleSave = (id, text) => {
    if (text.length === 0) {
      this.props.deleteTodo(id)
    }
  }

  handleStartClick = () => {
    this.incrementer = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({secondsStart:(this.state.secondsStart + 1)
      });
    }, 1000)
  }

  handleStopClick = () => {
    clearInterval(this.incrementer)
  }

  render() {
    const { todo, completeTodo, deleteTodo} = this.props

    let element
    if (this.state.todo) {
      element = (
        <TodoTextInput text={todo.text}
                       onSave={(text) => this.handleSave(todo.id, text)} />
      )
    } else {
      element = (
        <div className="view">
          <input className="toggle"
                 type="checkbox"
                 checked={todo.completed}
                 onChange={() => completeTodo(todo.id)} />
          <label>
            {todo.text}
          </label>
          <div className="buttons">
                <h6>{this.getHoures()}:{this.getMinutes()}:{this.getSeconds()}</h6>
                {(this.state.secondsStart === 0)
                ? <button className="timer-start" onClick={this.handleStartClick}>Start</button>
                : <button className="timer-stop" onClick={this.handleStopClick}>Stop</button> 
                }
          </div>
          <button className="destroy"
                  onClick={() => deleteTodo(todo.id)} />
        </div>
      )
    }
```

Sorry, maybe it is too big, but I really don't know what I can hide, maybe something will be useful.
I will be very appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `timer-stop` buttons you can add `disabled={ ! this.state.timerRunning && this.state.runningTaskId !== currentTaskId }`. For `timer-start` buttons add `disabled={ this.state.timerRunning }` This will disable which will disable all start buttons when timer is running.

You can control the above states in `handleStartClick() / handleStopClick()` methods.

Comment: As I right understood, these states I can control like this:

  handleStartClick = () => {
    this.incrementer = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({secondsStart:(this.state.secondsStart + 1)
      });
    }, 1000)
     this.setState({
      timerRunning: true
    });
  }

Comment: Yes. Check react setState method for exact details.

Comment: Thank you, it was really helpful for me.

Comment: You are welcome. If it answers your quesrion please mark it as answered so that others can save time.

Comment: Sorry, but issue still here.I think I do smth wrong in state:
handleStartClick = () => {
    if (!this.state.timerRunning) {
      this.incrementer = setInterval(() => {
        this.setState({
          secondsStart: (this.state.secondsStart + 1)
        });
      }, 1000)
      this.setState({
        timerRunning: true,
        currentTodoId: this.props.todo.id,
        runningTodoId: this.props.todo.id
      });
    }
}
  handleStopClick = () => {
    clearInterval(this.incrementer)
    this.setState({ timerRunning: false, currentTodoId: null, runningTodoId: null });
}